# Reading and storing a set of data from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have set of data stored in Firebase Realtime Database (snapshot attached). 
[Click to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0zqX.png)
I want to read this data when I press a button in my Android app and store it according to the person name, for example storing that Jack is 20 years old and Marry is an engineer, but I need to do this for more than just 3 users.

I'm able to call the data and read it but storing it in the way I described above is not working.

EDIT:

I added part of the code I'm working with, my main goal is when I click a button to call the data from Database, I'm able to do this but I can't figure out the best way to store this data in a way that I can use it. For example I want to display the name of the user and his role and age but I want to do this for as many users as available in database.

[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqtZQ.png)

Comment: Do you want to store locally ?

Comment: @JDevoloper yes but I don't want to permanently store it, I just want to retrieve it when the button is pressed.

Comment: ok, if you want to store items that you have clicked, you need to use Room Persistance database. when you clicked the button you need to insert it. if you want to learn about room persistance database you can check this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4...... you will not need live data. but its really helpfull to learn room database tutorial..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Can you show the code that _is not working_ ? Relevant part of log may be useful also.

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited the post and added part of the code

Comment: @Benoit .I edited the post and added part of the code